# How to get the url of an object in a private bucket s3 amazon(not presigned)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

What I need is a url that can access the private bucket's file without having it changed to public access.
I understand that there is the direct url format but it is only limited to public access buckets. I also know that there is the presigned URL but it will only be available within a time limit. so to iterate the question, is there a way to get a url for a private bucket without having the time limit.

Please leave a message if I'm being unclear anywhere thank you!

Comment: A private url without having the time limit = making the object public

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can set bucket policies and only make certain files of the bucket publicly available.
[see here in documentation](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/read-access-objects-s3-bucket/)